# How to check SSL expiry in Azure VMs using Azure Powershell Runbooks

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I need to check SSL expiry for all Azure VMS in a subscription, using powershell and runbooks in Azure what's the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can refer to [Get Azure Certificates Expiration date](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/brntm7/get_azure_certificates_expiration_date/), [Get Started with Azure Automation](https://theithollow.com/2016/09/19/get-started-azure-automation/) and http://encamina.com/articulos_tecnicos/english/How_to_generate_Lets_Encrypt_SSL_Certificates_with_Azure_Automation.pdf

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have your certificates stored in [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server), you can use the [Get-AzKeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvault?view=azps-6.3.0) and [Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-6.3.0) cmdlets to work up a PS script that checks if any of your certs are nearing the expiration date. Here is a sample PS snippet:

```
$Result = @()

# Get all certificates from all Key Vaults in your Subscription
$AllCerts = Get-AzKeyVault | Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate

# Check for certs expiring in the next 90 days
foreach($Cert in $AllCerts)
{
    if($Cert.Expires -lt ((Get-Date).AddDays(90)))
    {
        $Result += $Cert
    }
}

$Result | ft -Property Name, VaultName, Enabled, Created, NotBefore, Updated, Expires, Id
```

Sample output:

[image: Sample Output]

When done, you can run this script within a [PowerShell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity#create-powershell-runbook). Do take note of configuring a [Run As account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/create-run-as-account) in Azure Automation for being able to manage your Azure resources using the runbook.